# What is the price range to rent a motorbike in Myanmar for a day?

Tags: rental, price, motorcycles, myanmar

I've been reading several blogs, guide books and magazines and I'm a bit confused about what is the right price range to pay for rent a motorbike (scooter) one day (24 hours). For instance, in Vietnam I've been paying around $6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Ridetheworld](http://ridetheworld.com/?geodir_search=1&stype=gd_place&s=rental&snear=myanmar&sgeo_lat=21.916221&sgeo_lon=95.95597399999997) lists two motorcycle rental locations in Myanmar together with a location map, although I'm not sure if it's accurate.

[Mandalay Motorcycle Rental](http://www.mandalaymotorbike.com/) offers scooters starting from approximately [US$8 per day](http://www.mandalaymotorbike.com/p/the-bikes.html).

[Myanmar Bike Rental](http://www.myanmarbikerental.com/) offers scooters starting from approximately [US$5 per day](http://www.myanmarbikerental.com/#bikes-pricing).

A three year old [thread](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/asia-south-east-asia-mainland/myanmar/motorbike-rental-in-mandalay) on lonely planet claims that hiring motorcycles is illegal for tourists in Myanmar as does [one](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g294190-i9408-k6617749-Motorbike_License_in_Myanmar-Myanmar.html) on Trip advisor.

[Go-myanmar](http://www.go-myanmar.com/by-motorbike) provides useful information on motorcycling in Myanmar and mentions that using motorbikes is only illegal in some areas:

> If you are after the freedom of the road, many parts of Myanmar are
>   best explored by motorbike. Self drive car hire is not possible, so
>   motorbikes offer you the chance to take long-distance trips on your
>   own schedule, and allow you access to remote parts of Myanmar that
>   often have rough roads.
>
> In most parts of the country motorbikes are simple and cheap to hire,
>   usually costing around K10,000 per day. Most large- and medium-sized
>   towns (and all major tourist spots, other than Bagan) offer motorbike
>   hire; it is usually simplest to ask at your hotel or guest house.
>
> - Using motorbikes in Yangon is illegal (some locals are granted a
>     special permit).
> - Using motorbikes in Bagan is not permitted for
>     foreigners (but e-bikes and bicycles are allowed).

You might be advised to check into the legal situation and cofirm whether or not you will be insured in such a case.

Answer (score 3):

I rented a scooter for 24 hours in March 2016, we paid 8000 Kyat (about 6.20 Euro / 7 USD) . This was for an automatic scooter (new model) at a proper place with paperwork and everything.

Manual scooters are cheaper but I don't remember exact prices.

Also this was in a town in the deep south, not many tourists there. In Bagan and Inle lake prices may be higher. It seems in touristy places they charge higher prices because there is more demand.

Answer (score 2):

You can ride the motorbike in many places in Myanmar except Yangon and Bagan. 
The price is about 7usd/ day to 15usd/ day depending on the bike version.

Some tour operators provide bikes tours :
[Myanmar Motorcycles](http://myanmarmotorcycles.com/) or 
[Myanmar Tours](http://www.myanmartours.net/burma-motorcycle-adventures.html).
Jack from Mandalay is a very knowledgeable rider, guide as well. His site is mentioned above for bike rental